# .Net Core 2 not building my SPA because it can't Exec properly?

Tags: build, csproj, .net-core-2.0

I have created an React+Redux using the .Net Core 2.0 template. **I didn't change anything** yet it's not buildind.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning   MSB3073 The command "node --version" exited with code
>   1.    WebApplication2 C:\Tests\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\WebApplication2.csproj 25

Yet, node is properly installed, when I run "node --version" in a prompt (from any drive/directory) I get `v8.4.0` and no error code (the expected behaviour).

I tried **using the full path** in the .csproj file.

```
<Exec Command="&quot;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node&quot; --version" ContinueOnError="true">
  <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode" />
</Exec>
```

And I'm still getting the same error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning   MSB3073 The command ""C:\Program Files\nodejs\node" --version"
>   exited with code
>   1.    WebApplication2 C:\Tests\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\WebApplication2.csproj 25

I **reinstalled NodeJS**, with the same results.

Then I even tried a dummy task calling dos **`echo 0`** and it still fails.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning   MSB3073 The command "echo 0" exited with code
>   1.    WebApplication2 C:\Tests\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\WebApplication2.csproj 25

What's going on?

Here's the whole segment which does the check:

```
<Target Name="DebugRunWebpack" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' And !Exists('wwwroot\dist') ">
  <!-- Ensure Node.js is installed -->
  <Exec Command="&quot;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node&quot; --version" ContinueOnError="true">
    <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode" />
  </Exec>
  <Error Condition="'$(ErrorCode)' != '0'" Text="Node.js is required to build and run this project. To continue, please install Node.js from https://nodejs.org/, and then restart your command prompt or IDE." />

  <!-- In development, the dist files won't exist on the first run or when cloning to
       a different machine, so rebuild them if not already present. -->
  <Message Importance="high" Text="Performing first-run Webpack build..." />
  <Exec Command="node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.vendor.js" />
  <Exec Command="node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js" />
</Target>
```

Comment: can you try this on another machine as well? which version of windows are you using? (I am unable to reproduce this using your samples..)

Comment: Windows 7, I tried another machine (in the same organization I'm working in) and got the same result. But then I tried running the command in a "Command prompt" run in admin mode and it worked.

Comment: Oh.. managed enterprise environment?

Comment: Yes and obviously featuring some adverse effects on development tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This had been related to security issue of some sort.

Running "dotnet run" from a command prompt run with **admin** rights "fixed" the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue (I realized that my node_modules folder wasn't there) so I upgraded my .Net Core app to 2.1 and ran npm i and that worked.
Doesn't hurt to just try npm i and try again